# wordpress создание модального окна для каждого поста в цикле

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bootstrap

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании цикла для вывода постов, не понимаю как при нажатии на пост перейти на модальное окно, в котором будет выводиться контент именно того поста, по которому кликнет пользователь.

```
          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <figure class="effect-lily">
              <?php if (function_exists('add_theme_support'))
                the_post_thumbnail ();  ?>
              <figcaption>
                <div>
                  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                </div>                
              </figcaption>     
            </figure>
        </a>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>           
      </div>
      </div>

 <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Надеюсь на ваше понимание )))

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Всё содержимое `figure` поместить в `.modal-body` и вместо `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">` этой же ссылкой вызывать модальное окно. Но и сам код модального окна нужно поместить в цикл, например после `</a>`